# Link to launch modal window instead of image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I was hoping someone could help me, as I'm an amateur coder and I've spent the last 3 or 4 hours trying to figure this out.  Instead of clicking on the window to launch my image in the modal, how do I make it so it's simply clicking a link to launch it?  Thanks for the help!  Here is javascript, CSS, and html:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

modal.addEventListener('click',function(){
this.style.display="none";
})

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Get all images and insert the clicked image inside the modal
// Get the content of the image description and insert it inside the modal image caption
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```css
img.responsive {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  margin: 30px;
  float: left;
}

img.responsive:hover {
  border: 2px solid hotpink;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Clear Floats */

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<img class="responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/cQy7Yg.jpg">
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pls remove the JAVA tag

Comment: This is Javascript and all Java developers like me will cry when they see that

Comment: Thank you for the change

Comment: so sorry about that, fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make following changes in your code to do that. Hope it helps!

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

modal.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
})

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}



function launchModal(element) {
  // Get all images and insert the clicked image inside the modal
  // Get the content of the image description and insert it inside the modal image caption
  //var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  //var i;
  //for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  //images[i].onclick = function() {
  modalImg.src = element.getAttribute('data-src');
  modalImg.alt = this.alt;
  captionText.innerHTML = element.parentElement.children[1].innerHTML;
  modal.style.display = "block";
  //}
  //}
}
```

```css
img.responsive {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  margin: 30px;
  float: left;
}

img.responsive:hover {
  border: 2px solid hotpink;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Clear Floats */

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a onclick="launchModal(this)" href="#" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/cQy7Yg.jpg"> Launch Modal </a>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>



<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!  Is it possible to remove the img entirely, and just work off of a link?  If I try to put two of these modal links into the same paragraph, it will only use the image for the first one.

Comment: Problem solved, another user helped me:
The issue is that both elements have the same parent so you will always select the same image using parentElement.children[1].An idea is to include the image link as a data attribute inside the link itself and avoid extra elements.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You don't need img element for src of the image. Directly, put data-src in link element. and on click of link, use that "data-src" value and set it in img src attribute of Modal Image.

Comment: Additionally, I have made the edits in above snippet too, so that others can also make use of it. Please mark it accepted, if it has solved your problem completely.